# Can I make pancakes with a normal frying pan?

Tags: skillet

I want pancakes and the recipe says use a skillet

Comment: What kind of pancakes? American style fluffy pancakes, crepes or something else?

Comment: Who told you a skillet is anything other than a frying pan?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use a normal frying pan to make pancakes, assuming you have a stove.

I am chiefly familiar with the [definition of skillet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skillet) that is equivalent to frying pan, but I see that there is a British definition that is a pot with feet for cooking on a hearth.

Comment: As a 60-year-old Brit, let me say that is not the definition that would spring to mind… or rather not one I've ever come across before. In fact I think I'd be more inclined to call a cast-iron pot on 3 legs a *cauldron*, cue halloween music ;)